# Is there a way to configure the variable name Resharper suggests?

Tags: visual-studio, mocking, resharper

I find myself writing `new Mock<ISomeClass>();` then <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>
The result is (R# creates a variable):

```
var mock = new Mock<ISomeClass>();
```

I want it to be:

```
var someClassMock = new Mock<ISomeClass>();
```

Is there a way to configure the name Resharper gives the variable?

Comment: It uses rather simple patterns to determine a new name. I find it enough to use the suggested one then F2 into it.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I could recommend is creating a ReSharper live template to insert this for you. I use something very similar myself with [FakeItEasy](http://fakeiteasy.github.io/). Here's how you could do it:

1. Create a new Live Template called (ReSharper -> Templates Explorer -> C# -> New Template)
2. Set the Shortcut to `mock`, add a description
3. Create this expression body: `var $VARIABLE$Mock = new Mock<$TYPE$>();`
4. **Important:** make sure the order of the parameters is `TYPE` first, `VARIABLE` second
5. Click **Choose Macro** on the `VARIABLE` parameter, and select "Value of another variable with the first character in lower case"

It should look something like this:

[image]

Now when you go to your code and type `mock`, you'll generate a pattern where you would type your class or interface name inside `new Mock<>()`, and it will prepend the name automatically. Sadly, I haven't found a good way to remove the `i` from the generated name if it's an interface, so that's something you'll have to do manually...

Hope that helps.